# Clear TextField in QML on Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have a simple textfield:

```
TextField {
       id: searchField
       height: Units.dp * 40
       color: Palette.colors["white"]["500"]
       textColor: Palette.colors["white"]["500"]
       placeholderText: qsTr("Search...")

}
```

And I'm trying to clear TextField input as following:

```
function clearSearch() {
    Qt.inputMethod.reset()
    Qt.inputMethod.hide()
    searchField.focus = false
    searchField.text = ""
}
```

It seems that on Android function clearSearch doesn't work. What I see that text input still contains last entered text (I guess it is a displayText). Also I suppose that it is due autocomplete feature of the keyboard.

Am I clearing a text input the wrong way?

My test case:

1. Enter something in the field, using virtual keyboard with autocomplete.
2. Do not confirm input, leaving current word selected (underlined)
3. Tap clear button (call to clearSearch())
4. Notice that there is still an underlined text in a TextField
5. Tap on a field again, and see that keyboard shows again, and text field is empty now

P.S. Qt 5.5

Comment: Usually`searchField.text = ""` is sufficient to clear the field. You are either a) not calling `clearSearch` correctly or b) there's difference between `text` property and [`displayText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#displayText-prop). If the second case you can just write  `searchField.displayText = ""`.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo, thx for suggestion. I'm calling clearSearch properly, I've tested that with debugger. Sure there's a difference between text and displayText. And displayText is a readonly property. This code works fine on desktop platform. I'm experiencing a problem only with virtual keyboard

Comment: Ah yes, my bad for the property. :) It still seems strange. Never had a clear problem. It sounds like there's something else going on.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo the interesting thing is that when I tap on a text field, activating focus again, it clears as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `Qt.inputMethod.reset()` to reset any partial uncommitted text input from an input method.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I tried that, unfortunately It didn't work for me.

Comment: You are right. This completely solved the problem. It didn't work because of other lines. It should be just one call of ```Qt.inputMethod.reset()```, nothing else. Thank you!